# Tag wiki preview contains html tags

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

The tag wiki preview that's displayed when doing a search like [`[python] a`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+a) is screwed up for me on Chrome 71:

[image]

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: yes, the same for all the tags